# When would "no mapper" be needed?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have been using no reducer jobs for a while in certain use cases but I never came across "no mapper" job yet. "No Mapper" means that still the mapreduce framework will read input files and shuffle/sort them in some fashion (based on InputFormat?) and those will be an input to my reducer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"No mapper" is a euphemism for "identity mapper".  The default mapper if you don't specify one is just that.  At the very least, the identity mapper process directs the unchanged inputs to the right reducer partitions.

Answer (score 2):

In case you use Hadoop Streaming:

```
-mapper "/bin/sh -c \"cat\""
```

Answer (score 1):

For some of the aggregation functions based on the input key a identity mapper makes sense. The mapper will emit the same i/o keys as the input to it and the reducer will aggregate the values for a particular key.